# How to set a background image for all pages in reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, background-image

I tried to set a image to all pages as background.
I have tried to set the style of the body tag of `index.html`

```
<body style="background-image: url(%PUBLIC_URL%/bp.jpg)">
```

But this did not do anything.
So I tried to add it to the `body` tag in index.css in `src/`. I have moved the picture from the public folder to `/src`.

But this did not do anything too.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-image: url("./bg.jpg");
}
```

So my last try was the App.css where my routing is:

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CharacterFormView from "./views/CharacterFormView";
import SkillTreeView from "./views/SkillTreeView";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>

        <Route exact path="/" component={CharacterFormView}/>
        <Route path="/character-form" component={CharacterFormView}/>
        <Route path="/skill-trees" component={SkillTreeView}/>

      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
    .App {
      text-align: center;
      background: url("./bg.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    
    }
```

This last try set the background image to the first two routes `"/"` and `"/character-form"`.
Even there it is not full screen only till the half of the page.
If I go to `"/skill-trees"` - there is no image in the background

So how can I set the same picture as background img for all pages? The image should not repeat just full screen. I'm sure there's a better way as setting it in every .css file of my project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The background can be included in your App.css, but you need to use it like this:

```
 .App {
      text-align: center;
      background-image: url("./bg.jpg"); // here you had it wrong
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

This way your background will be rendered in your main component, App.js in your case, therefore, in all its children

Comment: my syntax is valid css. Look at [this.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

And I tried your solution too but it still shows the background img till the half of the page. The other half is blank. And it is not working on /skill-trees like I described in the question

Comment: What may be happening to you is that the height of your elements is defining the height of your page.
I usually create a top element with `height: 100vh` and all the childrens can use `height: 100%` to expand to the whole height of my page.

You may need to add `overflow: auto` for them to properly scroll but you will be sure that your element is covering the whole page and thus having a background image.

Comment: @LucasPadovan thank you very much. This fixed the problem. I set .App to height: 100vh. After that the img expanded to full size on all pages